# JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<' in titanium

Tags: ios, iphone, json, titanium, titanium-mobile

I'm receiving the error JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'. but only on IOS. in android it is working fine and the JSON seams to be right. (You can put the link in your web browser and se). The error is in this line Data = JSON.parse(this.responseText); but i can't understand why. and why does is work on android and not in IOS?

```
var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
            onload : function(e) {
                Data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                Size = Object.keys(Data).length;
                AddList();
            },
            onerror : function(e) {
            },
            timeout : 15000
        });
        client.open("GET", http://lamadeus.virtualweb.pt/site/app_mobile/teste.php?act=getprodsdestaque);
        client.send();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried printing the responseText on iOS? Usually this error indicates that the request is receiving a HTML instead of JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Check after replacing :

`<` with `&lt;`

`>` with `&gt;`

`&` with `&amp;` in your `this.responseText` and after that try to parse.